# $\overline{A}=A\cup \{p\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and suppose that $x_n \rightarrow p$. Let $A$ be the set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$, how to prove that $\overline{A}=A \cup \{p\}$.

The inclusion $A \cup \{p\} \subset \overline{A}$ is trivial. The other inclusion is easily proven in the case where $X$ is a metric space, [(as seen in this link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377801/closure-of-convergent-sequence), but I have no idea how to prove the other inclusion in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $x\in X\setminus(A\cup\{p\})$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$ and $p\in V$. The sequence converges to $p$, so there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in V$ for all $n\ge m$. Can you now find an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A$?

Comment: If I prove that $X\setminus (A\cup \{p\})$ is open, how does that help to show that $\overline{A}=A \cup \{p\}$?

Comment: @VictorHugo: My suggested argument is not just showing that $X\setminus(A\cup\{p\})$ is open: it’s showing that $x\notin\operatorname{cl}A$.

Comment: Perfect, now I understand, thank you!

Comment: @VictorHugo: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Prove that the complement of $A\cup \{p\}$ is open, by using the Hausdorff criterion and the definition of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

$K=A \cup \{p\}$ is compact (for eny open cover of it, the open set that contains $p$ contains all but finitely many $x_n$, by convergence, so we need fintiely many more to cover $K$ in full). And a compact subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed. So $\overline{K}=K$ as required.